# принудительно прерывание функции, если условие перестало выполняться

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть функция, которая запускается при прокрутке страницы до определенного места.(к примеру до (`top>800`)
Если мы прокрутим страницу обратно ((`top<800`), то функция продолжит выполняться, пока не завершиться полностью.

**Вопрос:** Как сделать так, чтобы выполнение функции остановилось, если условие перестало выполняться?
 выглядит это все примерно так:

```js
  function add() {
    $("ul li").each(function(i, el) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        $(el).addClass("active");
      }, 0 + (i * 800));
    });
  }

  function remove() {
    $("ul li").each(function(i, el) {
      $(el).removeClass("active");
    });
  }
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var top = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (top > 300) {
      add();
    } else {
      remove()
    }
  })
```

```css
body {
  height: 2800px;
}
ul {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
}
li {
  background: #FF9800;
  margin: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  color: #fff;
}
li.active {
  background: #8BC34A;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: никак, если попали в  `else` значит addcl - не запущена и прерывать нечего

Comment: ))) если я попал в if то запускается функция которая начинает добалаять классы с интервалом 800ms, если прокручу наверх то функция не остановится, просто будет выполнен else который не позволит запустить ее снова. Нет ли способа в else ee прервать?

Comment: дополнил вопрос, посмотрите, как работает, не знаю как прервать...

Answer (score 1):

Сделайте в проверку в add - `if (false)` -  выход из функции

```js
function add() {
  if (runAddcl == true) {
    $("ul li").each(function(i, el) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() < 300) return;
        $(el).addClass("active");
      }, 0 + (i * 800));
    });
  }
}

function remove() {
  $("ul li").each(function(i, el) {
    $(el).removeClass("active");
  });
}
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var top = $(window).scrollTop();
  if (top > 300) {
    add();
  } else {
    remove()
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  height: 2800px;
}
ul {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
}
li {
  background: #FF9800;
  margin: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  color: #fff;
}
li.active {
  background: #8BC34A;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: яваскрипт - однопоточный - пока вы крутитесь в бесконечном цикле вы не можете в другом месте флаг выставить чтобы выйти из цикла

Comment: кажется тут бы пригодилась, событийная ориентированность... То есть способа реализовать то, что я хочу, нет?

Comment: @Grundy
да, верно, исправил на `if` ... Спасибо

Comment: @CodeGust и пришли к тому, что у меня в вопросе)))

Comment: @ЕвгенийШевцов
А если в самом `add` делать проверку `$(window).scrollTop()>300` и выход при `false`?

Answer (score 0):

Вся проблема в setTimeout, так-как вся функция уже выполняется ,а таймеры выполняются через время, нам нужно, либо в функции setTimeout **добавить проверку** - нужно ли ещё выполнять это действие, когда время выйдет или удалять таймеры, когда нужно остановить функцию, через **clearTimeout**